# MySQL - Can not connect from local network, but can connect from any other IP

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, database

Facing a really strange issue.

The original requirement was to have a development server which can be accessed from our office in Sweden and from India.

In our server in Stockholm, I created a new Ubuntu VM(Ubuntu 15.04, 64 bit), and gave it an IP 192.168.3.127. I installed MySQL in it(5.6.24) and modified the `bind-address` in `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` to `0.0.0.0`

I setup port forwarding in the router to forward `3306` to 192.168.3.127 and then created a new database using

`CREATE DATABASE mydatabase;`

I granted permissions for a user

`GRANT ALL PERMISSIONS ON mydatabase.* to 'someuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'supersecretpassword!';`

Now, developers are able to connect from India using the public IP of Sweden office, but developers inside the Sweden office can not connect to the server. They can connect to it using the local IP(192.168.3.127), but not using the public IP.

I wonder what is wrong. Any ideas?

Vivek

Comment: this can happen on some router , check if you can ping your external IP from inside, I have the same issue on one of my home routers, but not on the work one.

Comment: @DennisNolte Yes, I can ping my external IP from inside. I can even access other port forwarded applications(for e.g.: a web application running on port 80) using the public IP. Just MySQL giving me much grief

Comment: so you have a router able to do this and my info is not valid for your case.

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing DNAT from outside network to your inside network, the external users can access your internal server using the public IP correctly as you have done. The public IP is NATed to private IP and forwarded to server.

However, your internal users will not be able to access the same server using the public IP unless NAT is fixed to allow this too. There should be another DNAT rule to translate the public IP internally before forwarding it to server.

Another possible solution is to use DNS names and define DNS views. Create an internal view which maps name to private IP, and create an external view which maps name to public IP. So, you will end up using same name internally and externally.